# Isomorphism between $U(\mathbb{Z}_{36})$ and $C_2 \times C_6$

Tags: group-theory

I know $U(\mathbb{Z}_{36})$ and $C_2 \times C_6$ are isomorphic, but how can I find the mapping of the elements?

Can I take the generators of $U(\mathbb{Z}_{36})$, map them into the generators of $C_2 \times C_6$ (preserving element order) and say it defines an isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Chinese remainder theorem:
$
\mathbb Z_{36} \cong \mathbb Z_{4} \times \mathbb Z_{9}
$
to induce
$
U(\mathbb Z_{36}) \cong U(\mathbb Z_{4}) \times U(\mathbb Z_{9}) \cong C_2 \times C_6
$.

The isomorphism
$
\mathbb Z_{36} \to \mathbb Z_{4} \times \mathbb Z_{9}
$
is the natural one
$
[x]_{36} \mapsto ([x]_4, [x]_9).
$

The isomorphism
$
U(\mathbb Z_{4}) \times U(\mathbb Z_{9}) \to C_2 \times C_6
$
relies on known primitive roots mod $4$ and mod $9$ and discrete logarithms with respect to these  primitive roots.

Perhaps it is easier to go in the other direction
$
C_2 \times C_6
\to
U(\mathbb Z_{4}) \times U(\mathbb Z_{9})
\to
U(\mathbb Z_{36}) 
$.
The first map still depends on primitive roots but is much easier to define. The second map is induced by the Chinese remainder theorem and requires solving Bézout's identity $4x+9y=1$.